# Removing Locks in Oracle 10

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have an issue when trying to update a column value in sqlplus.

It basically wont complete and just hangs. I am wondering if there is anyway to remove locks in oracle by force?

I've noticed a table called v$locked_object which does contain an onject ID relevant to the issue I am having.

Hope I've explained this good enough.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you find _what_ process was locking the object and what that process was doing? Surely it's better to fix the problem than hacking around it? (I'm fairly sure the answer to your question is no).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This will exactly serve your purpose:

```
SELECT SESSION_ID FROM DBA_DML_LOCKS WHERE NAME = <TABLE_NAME>;
```

Use the `SESSION_ID` to find the corresponding `SERIAL#` with this statement:

```
SELECT SID, SERIAL# FROM V$SESSION WHERE SID IN (
    SELECT SESSION_ID FROM DBA_DML_LOCKS WHERE NAME = <TABLE_NAME>
);
```

Locate the offending tuples `SID, SERIAL#` and release it like this:

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'SID, SERIAL#';
```

Comment: I managed to resolve this issue by finding the holding session within the application after checking dba_blockers. But will remember the ALTER command for the future. Can't vote up the answer due to low rep. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mari, thank you for these commands. I was able to free up the locked table in my db. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve this issue.

I looked in DBA_BLOCKERS table and got the session ID. Then killed the session and the lock was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, somebody else has updated the same table and hasn't committed yet. It might even be you (in a different tool or a different session).

The easiest way to get rid of the lock is to commit the work in the other session.

Comment: Hi I have managed to find the cause of this issue by looking in DBA_BLOCKERS. Got the Session ID and killed it.